# Power of continuous metric function is differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

I read in a paper, that if a metric function is continous, there is a power $k$, s.t.
$f^{k}$ is differentiable.
I'm not sure how to prove this. 
Does anyone know the argument?

Comment: How about the Devil's staircase (Cantor's function)?

Comment: Are you sure about the problem statement ?

Comment: It was a general metric function, like the absolute value function, which is not differentiable in zero, because of the kink, and they said they can find a power s.t. this general metric function is differentiable

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=e^{|x|}$ and $k \in \mathbb N.$ Then $f^k$ is not differentiable in $x=0.$